# Find all changed objects for a given user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I have a model `Car` which `has_paper_trail`. How can I find all `cars` which where changed or created by `current_user`? I could loop through all of them but that is a performance nightmare. Some `where` search is what I'm searching for but can't find.

Comment: DO you have column for changed and created_by in Cars table ?

Comment: I have `updated_at` and `created_at` in the `Car` table. But how does that help to find the `cars` which were created/changed by `current_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `whoddunnit` column in the `versions` table which you can query in conjunction with `item_type`, but it's only useful if it is recorded properly.

A simple query to get IDs of the modified records:

```
PaperTrail::Version.where(whodunnit: current_user.id, item_type: 'Car').select('distinct item_id')
```

See also https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change

Comment: But how can I do the reverse search? I know how to find the `User` who did the last change but I don't know how to find the last changes by the `current_user`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me:

    >> Version.where(whodunnit: current_user.id, item_type: 'Car').select(:item_id).distinct
    NameError: uninitialized constant Version
      from (irb):3
      from /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
      from /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
      from /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
      from bin/rails:4:in `require'
      from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    >>

Comment: @wintermeyer yep, sorry, it's called `PaperTrail::Version` since Papertrail version 3.